# Firebase Realtime Database Query Not Completing

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity3d-editor

I'm back to a project after not working on it for four months. Everything used to work fine before. The project uses Firebase Authentication, and that part seems okay. But now, there's a problem when trying to get data from the Firebase Realtime Database.

Here's the code causing trouble:

```
Query databaseQuery = Database.RootReference.Child(AppSettings.Version).Child("versions").OrderByChild("version").StartAt(currentVersion);
databaseQuery.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error: " + task.Exception);
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted)
    {
        Debug.Log("Query completed successfully");
        // More code to handle the result
    }
});
```

I've tried to figure out the issue but can't. The function isn't doing anything – no errors, no completion, no messages. I've double-checked Firebase logging and it's set to debug. The project uses Firebase SDK 10.6 and Unity3D version 2022.1.18f.

I also looked at the Firebase database security roles, and they seem fine. I haven't changed anything. I even tried a different query with another path, but it's still not working.

Is there something new with Google Firebase that might be causing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the internet? Is your database location set correctly?

Comment: Ditto the above: Try printing outside of the if and else block as there are other possible statuses.

Comment: I am sure I am connected, I can see Auth Current user, and I can see the Database path is correct. 
If the path is not correct it will back with complete but no data exists. 
I download my last version from google play, which was working perfectly and many users were able to connect. It is not working at all now. 
The only thing I can think of there is some google has changed something.